# Measurability of an a.s limit

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space, $(\mathcal{F}_n)_n$ a decreasing
sequence of sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{F}.$ Let $(X_n)_n$ be a sequence of r.v. converging a.s to $X.$ Prove that if for all $n \in \mathbb{N}, X_n$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable then $X$ is $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable.

We need to show that for a fixed $n \in \mathbb{N},U \in B(\mathbb{R}),X^{-1}(U) \in \mathcal{F}_n. 
$

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for all $n$
$$\{X \in U\} = \bigcap_{q \in \mathbb N} \bigcup_{r \geq n} \bigcap_{m \geq r} \{X_m + 1/q \in U\} \cup \{X_m - 1/q \in U\}.$$

Now, $\{X_m + 1/q \in U\} \cup \{X_m - 1/q \in U\}$ is $\mathcal F_n$-measurable for all $m \geq n$ because $(\mathcal F_n)_n$ is decreasing. So,
$$\bigcap_{m \geq r} \{X_m + 1/q \in U\} \cup \{X_m - 1/q \in U\}$$
is $\mathcal F_n$-measurable for all $r \geq n$. So,
$$\bigcup_{r \geq n} \bigcap_{m \geq r} \{X_m + 1/q \in U\} \cup \{X_m - 1/q \in U\}$$
is $\mathcal F_n$-measurable, and therefore so is
$$\bigcap_{q \in \mathbb N} \bigcup_{r \geq n} \bigcap_{m \geq r} \{X_m + 1/q \in U\} \cup \{X_m - 1/q \in U\}.$$

Comment: Why do we have the first equality? (We have almost sure convergence, not pointwise)

Comment: @john In that case, I'm not sure it's true unless the spaces $(\Omega, \mathcal F_n, P)$ are complete because in general a.s. equality of random variables doesn't imply measurability without completeness.

Comment: They didn't mention completeness of the space